# TeamCity API call to get a list of modifications to a build configuration

Tags: teamcity

I'm running TeamCity Enterprise 2019.2.4 (build 72059).

Is there an easy API call to get the username of a person who disabled a build step?

If that is not possible, as I suspect, what's the API endpoint to get a list of all modifications for a build configuration, and then the endpoint to get the contents of that modification?

Mind you, this is not about VCS changes. I know how to get those.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled versioned settings for that project, so I just check the git history for the file that represents the build configuration and parse the commits for the one that disabled the build step.